# Exception when trying to use a <vector> as src for an ImageView

Tags: android

I have in one of my layout files.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_app"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

My ic_app.xml is located in flavor/res/drawable. I notice that if I move the icon into main/res/drawable. Everything is working again!

The drawable ic_app is an XML. But for some reason, my android API-23 phone would crash whenever this activity is launched that contains this ImageView. Saying that the resource is not found.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.app.android.view.activity.login.WelcomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class ImageView

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class ImageView

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_app.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02029e
```

I have never seen this happening before. What could the cause be?

The same app runs correctly in an API-19 device.

Comment: what is inside `@drawable/ic_app` ?

Comment: Show your full `.xml` please, have you tried `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_app"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using vector drawables, use

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_app"
```

instead of

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_app"
```

Here is a [Good Read](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88)

Comment: This doesn't help. Still crashes. With a slightly different stacktrace. For some reason, if I move my icon out of the flavor/res to main/res it works!

Comment: your icon should be in your `main/res/drawable`...folder to correctly access it

Comment: Is there document for that? I am confused. Why do they have to be inside main/res?

Comment: There is official android documentation for different resource usage..Read it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_app"` instead of `android:src="@drawable/ic_app"`.

I've found this

> Firstly, when using AppCompat with ImageView (or subclasses such as ImageButton and FloatingActionButton), you’ll be able to use the new app:srcCompat attribute to reference vector drawables (as well as any other drawable available to android:src):

On this [Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Comment: This doesn't help. Still crashes. With a slightly different stacktrace. For some reason, if I move my icon out of the flavor/res to main/res it works!